# Discrepancy on minimum characters required between browser and Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, android-app, character-limit

App version: 1.0.31
Device: Nexus 7
Problem: When you are flagging a comment as `other`, you are required to enter at least 10 letters. Doing the same on a browser requires you to enter at least 6 characters. There is a difference of 4 characters (I know it's small and wouldn't make much difference), but consistency.

Android app:

> [image]

Browser:

> [image]

Comment: Same in iOS app.

Comment: You might be interested in [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)... ;)

Comment: @retailcoder ...why? How does that have anything to do with this question?

Comment: @Doorknob hehe.. the attention to details, *consistency* is a *frequently employed word* in CR answers. Reviewing other people's code can be a sport too, just like golf ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next update, thanks!

Comment: this bug is iOS also. should we put in a new bug report for that, or did you handle it in some back-end/shared code?

Comment: @mhlester Make a new one for iOS please

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230717/discrepancy-on-minimum-characters-required-between-browser-and-ios-app)