# Discrepancy on minimum characters required between browser and iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, ios-app, character-limit

Copied verbatim from: [Discrepancy on minimum characters required between browser and Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230598/discrepancy-on-minimum-characters-required-between-browser-and-android-app) (as requested by [Kasra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230598/discrepancy-on-minimum-characters-required-between-browser-and-android-app#comment757953_230716))

---

Problem: When you are flagging a comment as `other`, you are required to enter at least 10 letters. Doing the same on a browser requires you to enter at least 6 characters. There is a difference of 4 characters (I know it's small and wouldn't make much difference), but consistency.

iOS app:

[image]

Browser:

> [image]

Comment: Taking a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed a few versions ago.