# Do I need to separate bug reports for a same issue in Android app and iOS app?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app, bug-reports

If I see a bug in Android app and the same bug is in iOS app, is it recommended to create two separate bug reports for [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) and [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app)?

Or can I create a bug report just for [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) and add some note in the post that states the same issue is in iOS app too?

**Note:** I got this question after seeing the comments of this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230716/312043)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Kasra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/229741/kasra-rahjerdi?tab=profile) of our Mobile Team, one [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report is sufficient if it is reasonably apparent that it is the *same* problem in both platforms.

We would only try to split them up if separate bug reports have already been posted or it seems like the problem/solution may be slightly different for each platform.

In the case you cited (above), the problem was reported (and fixed) before the other platform was raised in the comments… so it was best to post a second report to get it back in the system.

Essentially, if you make it evident that the problem is present in both platforms **in the body of the post**, one bug report should be sufficient.